# Парсинг слова с сайта

Tags: html, парсер

Я взял блок с сайта, нужно спарсить "**необходимое слово**". Пытался сам, но выводит пустую строку.

```html
<div id="midler"><center><h1>Заголовок</h1>
Тут ненужный текст<br><br>
Текст:<br>
</center><center><font size="70px">необходимое слово
</font><br><br><br><br><a href="www.site.com">ссылка</a></center></div>
```

Comment: Что именно пытались-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('#<font[^>]*>(.*?)</font>#s', $string, $result);
var_dump(trim($result[1]));
```

Выводит:

```
string(33) "необходимое слово"
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Есть сайт http://regexr.com/ для регулярных выражений, может помочь сформировать нужный запрос

пример моего кода для проги парсинга на C# Winforms для вывода в таблицу которую потом можно было сделать в эксель для работы

мне нужны было выдрать с сайта почту, фио, телефоны, т.к. телефоны по разному указывались то это запросы reg2 - reg6

```
         private void DataLoad(string[] q) {
        MatchCollection matches;
        List<ParseData> l = new List<ParseData>();

        string fio = "";
        string phone = "";
        string post = "";

        //Виды запросов           
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"(mailto:)([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)");           
        Regex reg1 = new Regex(@"((\<b.*?\>)[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+(\</b.*?\>)(\<span.*?\>)[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+[\-\s][А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+[\-\s]?)");
        Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"\b\d{2}(\-)\d{2}"); //22-88
        Regex reg3 = new Regex(@"\b\d{3} \d{2} \d{2}"); //844 44 44
        Regex reg4 = new Regex(@"\b\d{7}"); //8444444
        Regex reg5 = new Regex(@"\(\d{4}\)\d{6}"); //(3333)333333
        Regex reg6 = new Regex(@"\(\d{4}\) \d{6}"); //(3333) 333333
        Regex reg7 = new Regex(@"((\<div class=\""position\"".*?\>)[А-ЯЁ][а-яё].*</div>)");
        Regex reg8 = new Regex(@"((\<div class=\""position\"".*?\>)[А-ЯЁ].*</div>)");

        foreach (var item in q) {
            string w = item.Replace(" </b>", "</b>").Replace("</b> <span>", "</b><span>").Replace("\ufeff", "");
            matches = reg1.Matches(item.Replace(" </b>", "</b>").Replace("</b> <span>", "</b><span>").Replace("\ufeff", "").Replace("\t", "").Replace("  ", " "));  //удаляем не нужны пробелы и т.д.
            if (matches.Count > 0) {
                foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {
                    if (fio != "") {
                        l.Add(new ParseData() { FIO = fio, Email = "", Tel = phone, Post = post });

                    }
                    fio = match.Value.Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", " ").Replace("<span>", "");

                }
            }


            matches = reg2.Matches(item);
            if (matches.Count > 0) {
                foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {                        
                    phone = match.Value;
                }
            } else {
                matches = reg3.Matches(item);
                if (matches.Count > 0) {
                    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {
                        phone = match.Value;
                    }
                } else {
                    matches = reg4.Matches(item);
                    if (matches.Count > 0) {
                        foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {
                            phone = match.Value;
                        }
                    } else {
                        matches = reg5.Matches(item);
                        if (matches.Count > 0) {
                            foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {
                                phone = match.Value;
                            }
                        } else {
                            matches = reg6.Matches(item);
                            if (matches.Count > 0) {
                                foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {
                                    phone = match.Value;
                                }
                            }                         
                        }                            
                    }
                }

            }
            matches = reg7.Matches(item);
            if (matches.Count > 0) {
                foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {
                    post = match.Value.Replace("<div class=\"position\">", "").Replace("</div>", "");
                }
            }
            matches = reg8.Matches(item);
            if (matches.Count > 0) {
                foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {
                    post = match.Value.Replace("<div class=\"position\">", "").Replace("</div>", "");
                }

            } 
            matches = reg.Matches(item);
            if (matches.Count > 0) {
                foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) {
                    l.Add(new ParseData() { FIO = fio, Email = match.Value.Replace("mailto:", ""), Tel = phone, Post = post });
                    fio = "";
                }
            }
        }
        var rowNumberWithPartitionBy = l
                      .OrderBy(o => o.FIO)
                      .GroupBy(g => g.FIO)
                      .Select(s => new { s, Count = s.Count() })
                      .SelectMany(sm => sm.s.Select(s => s)
                                        .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, sm.Count), (fruitTable, index)
                                            => new { Повторов = index, fruitTable.FIO, fruitTable.Email, fruitTable.Tel, fruitTable.FirstName, fruitTable.LastName, fruitTable.SecondName, fruitTable.Post })
                                  )
                                  .OrderBy(x => x.Повторов)
                                  .ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = rowNumberWithPartitionBy;
    }
```

и класс

```
 public class ParseData {
    string _FIO;
    public string FIO {
        get { return _FIO; }
        set {
            _FIO = value;
            ParseFIO(value);
        }
    }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public string Post { get; set; }
    private void ParseFIO(string data) {
        var example = data.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        FirstName = example[0];
        LastName = example[1];
        SecondName = example[2];
    }
}
```